# SearchJs and Agolia Custom Refinement List

Tags: jquery-chosen, algolia

Is anyone using libraries like ChosenJs select library to control their refinement list in Algolia Instantsearch? The issue I'm having is removing a single refinement from my custom wiget, while updating the refinement list and url. 
[Refinement List Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMzFM.png)
There's a **refine** method within the RefinementListRenderingOptions that applies a selection to the search and updates but there's no method that removes a single refinement and updates the existing search results.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a similar technique as described in the [custom widget guide](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/v2/guides/customization.html). Basically it goes like this:

1. use `connectRefinementList`
2. implement the "render" function using ChosenJS
3. add `refine` function with new items
4. add `refine` to existing items (will remove the refinement)

I hope that helps!